# Parse.com JS SDK multiple nested queries with include

Tags: parse-platform, subquery

**Setup:**

- A product, which has one pointer to brand and one pointer to shop
- A    brand, has name, ..
- A shop, has name, city, ...

**Query should get all products based on a filter, i.e.:**

- zero, one or more brand ids to which product.brand.id should match
- zero, one or more shop ids to which product.shop.id should match

I have the ids in an array, so basically what i want in the end:

```
    SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE product.shop.id IS IN shop_ids && product.brand.id IS IN brand_ids
```

I can't figure out how this has to be done, I've tried the following to get all products which include a brand id, which works. **BUT** the include does not work, **ALSO** beside the brands, it should check that the products are within a list of given shop ids

```
            for (var i = 0; i < brand_ids.length; i++)
            {
                var query = new Parse.Query(product);
                var brand = new Brand();
                brand.id = brand_ids[i];
                query.equalTo('brand', brand);
                query.include('brand');
                query.include('shop'); //TODO: where shop is one of [ids]

                queries.push(query);
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically create a list of queries and each of them can only match one id. You need to use the containedIn API https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_containedIn. Try the below code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(product);
var brands = [];
for (var i = 0; i < brand_ids.length; i++) {
    var brand = new Brand();
    brand.id = brand_ids[i];
    brands.push(brand);
};
query.containedIn('brand', brands);
query.include('brand');
query.include('shop'); //TODO: where shop is one of [ids]
query.find();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, i had to do the same for the shops.